# Get custom field values into the sidebar/widget?

Tags: custom-field, widgets, sidebar

I haven't seen this done, but I want to return the custom field values outside of the loop in the sidebar.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely doable with tons of different ways to accomplish it. Basically, you can use a [widget that allows for the execution of PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) or modify your theme files to execute PHP in the sidebar. The main function you will need is [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). You also need to access the post/page/CPT ID. You can use code like the following to get your post meta displayed.

```
global $wp_query;
if(is_object($wp_query->queried_object) && $wp_query->queried_object->ID)
{
    echo get_post_meta($wp_query->queried_object->ID, 'my_post_meta_key', true);
}
```

Obviously, you need to change the "my_post_meta_key" value to a key that corresponds to the meta data that you want. Also, there are other ways to access the current page/post/CPT ID, but since I do not know your specific context, this will work for most situations.

Comment: any chance of returning all meta, and exclude specific fields?

Comment: You can use `get_post_custom` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom), which will return an array of all of the custom fields. Then, in your `foreach` loop, you simply withhold the values that you do not want to process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID, then a call to get_post_meta() passing only the ID will get you an array of all the values:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the other answers? Or in which way is it more verbose than the others?

Comment: The asker asked if there was a way to return all the meta fields.Additionally, I wanted to test the water of SE as a new user and see if I got instantly jumped on for attempting an answer.

Comment: That's cool. Btw, look at get_post_custom()